# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not getting called

Tags: ios, url-scheme, armv7, arm64, swift2

I have an app with a URL scheme that opens the app fine, but the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` doesn't get called on both an iPhone 5c and iPod Touch 5 on iOS 8, while it works perfectly on my iPhone 6 on iOS 9.
I'm not sure if the problem is iOS 8 or armv7, as I don't have any armv7 devices running iOS 9, nor do I have any arm64 devices running iOS 8.

By the way, I am using Xcode 7 beta 1.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem.

Replacing

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    // analyze URL here
    return true
}
```

with

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleOpenURL url: NSURL) -> Bool {
    // analyze URL here
    return true
}
```

appears to have all the functionality I require, and works on all the devices I tested it on.